# Django - Method for uploading an image in format .tif and conver into JPEG

Tags: django, image

i'm new to django and i need to develop a function to upload an image in .tif format. I need to convert the image into JPEG and at the same time i want to save the original image which mean both of the image type will be save in the same directory. What is the correct method that i can use?

Answer (score 3):

First upload the file to server.Then convert it before save using `PIL`

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('image.tiff') #image.tiff from request.FILES
img.save('image.jpg', "JPEG")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find an example django project that accepts uploaded files here: https://github.com/axelpale/minimal-django-file-upload-example.

The PIL (Python Image Library) is dead. However there is an actively maintained fork you can use instead called [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.2.1).

You can get Pillow via pip as follows:

```
pip install Pillow
```

You can use Pillow to convert the saved tif file to jpeg as follows:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
example_path_to_tif = 'saved_files/test.tif'
corresponding_jpeg_path = os.path.join(os.path.splitext(example_path_to_tif)[0], '.jpeg')
im = Image.open(example_path_to_tif)
im.save(corresponding_jpeg_path , "JPEG")
```

This will save the jpeg into the same directory where the tif resides, and with the same filename (but different extension).

Comment: where should i put the code.. in views.py or models.py

Comment: i got this error 'function' object has no attribute 'rfind'

Comment: @IamMoon -- this can go either in views.py or models.py. If you're just starting out it may be simpler to put the logic in views.py, but over time you may find it is more organized for logic that changes state to go into models.py, and for code in views.py to be dedicated to interpreting input at the start and formatting output before returning it (with a call to model code inbetween).